# Make a bootable, preinstalled and persistent USB bootable linux system

Tags: linux, boot, mount, partition, dd

I have a debian 10 VM / Physical server, that I want to clone completely into a USB (DOK) Drive, and make it bootable.

Additionally - I need this DOK to be Read/Write and not only ROM like CDFS.

I know there are plenty of tools and methods, But I already tried a few and nothing gives me stable, and exact results.

Systemback "live system" is creating good bootable USB but I didn't manage to alter it properly to be RW after (Also seems like creating CDFS with weird configs).

Some of the other tools I tried were dd (I copied full partitions but it didn't came very stable, both the process and the outcome), mkusb and clonezilla.

Comment: I did this numerous times in various configurations. What is a DOK? Also do you want to run the VM or the host system from the USB drive?

Comment: @Hermann Awesome! thank you! DOK stand for Disk on Key.. It's just a USB drive. Yes, I want to run a full debian system out of the live USB system

Comment: Does that Debian 10 installation in the VM use full virtualisation with a BIOS or UEFI boot procedure? Or is some kind of para-virtualisation being used?

Comment: It is a fully installed UEFI, but I can also make a vmware version (or virtualbox)

Comment: Do you use a file-based disk image? If so, which format (raw, qcow2, vdi)?

Comment: The debian is installed on a regular ext4 partition, I don't mind what format it will be on the usb as long it's writable

Comment: Please add the output of `lsblk` for both host and virtual system to your question. So I can have a better understanding of the partition layout.

Comment: lsblk of the physical applice-
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM      SIZE  RO  TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0         1                  0   disk 
nvme0n1            259:0         1   238.5G   0    disk 
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1         0   512M     0    part   /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2   259:1         0   18.6G     0    part   /
└─nvme0n1p3   259:3         0   977M     0    part   [SWAP]

Comment: Only for testing VM lsblk -
sda      8:0    0   120G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 119.5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1  28.7G  0 disk 

sdb is the USB drive

Comment: So sda is a physical disk which is passed to the virtual machine? Why is the USB drive attached to the virtual machine? Is the USB host controller handed off to the virtual machine?

Comment: In the first comment, nvme0n1 is a physical disk, I didn't conenct the USB to it, 
In the second comment sda is a virtual disk (VMDK), the USB is just connected from VMware for the example purpose, I can get other USB if needed

Answer (score 0):

Since your virtual machine is stored on a VMDK file, you can simply store it on the USB drive while converting to raw:

```
sudo qemu-img convert -p -O raw source.vmdk /dev/disk/your-usb-drive
```

Of course, the virtual machine must be inactive. The USB-drive must be big enough for the entire VM storage.

Since the virtual machine has been set-up using full virtualisation and EFI boot style, no other actions are necessary.